# Conditional Operators

Tags: c, sizeof, conditional-operator

In the following code, when I fetch the value of the first `if`'s condition, it is 0, thus false. Still, the output prints "float". Is it a consequence of short circuiting ? If so, why doesn't it happen in the "normal" case, when the `sizeof` operator is not used with '==' ?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int x=1;
     short int i=2;
     float f=3;

     if(sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
         printf("float");
     else if(sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
         printf("Short int");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeof((x==2)?f:i)` returns the size of the static type of its argument. Its argument is `(x==2)?f:i`, which is of type `float` even if the condition is not true. This is because an expression type is not set in runtime, but during compilation.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `operator?:` must be the same type regardless of which operand is selected. In this case, the first `?:` results in `i` converted to a `float`, so the size is the same as the size of `float`.

We can see the precise method of determining the type in §6.5.15/5:

> If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be
>   determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands,
>   is the type of the result.

Skipping over to Usual Arithmetic Conversions, the relevant text is in §6.3.1.8/1:

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is float.

There you have it.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` does not execute its operand, and moreover is a compile-time operator, which means that you couldn't branch on non-constant values anyway.

`sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i)` is the size of the type of the result of `(x == 2) ? f : i`. The conditional operator would promote your `short` to a `float` if it were executed, so the whole `sizeof` expression is equivalent to `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: There's no promotion, only UAC.

Comment: *You need administrator privileges to perform this branch*. Ugh.

Comment: Hah. I'm still working on associating that with C++ before Windows.

Comment: Well, you just reminded me of the C++ meaning. I had completely forgotten this one (and Google doesn't help)... What's the difference with a promotion then ?

Comment: Promotions are integers to other integers and go up to `unsigned int` IIRC. They sometimes are the only thing that happens and sometimes happen before UAC. For example, both arguments to `operator+` will be converted to the result of UAC, but both arguments to `operator<<` will be promoted. Promotions can happen as part of UAC, too, with post-processing. I'm not as familiar with where each of these happens in C, but at least the standard will say on a case by case basis.

Comment: Oh, OK. So, promotions are conversions to a wider type, while UAC are for example from integers to reals.

Comment: I guess, though there's still things like `long long` to consider. Promotions will result in `int` if its range is a superset, else `unsigned int`. That would be where the rules of UAC come in following promotions: to handle things like `long long` vs. `unsigned long long`.